# Javafx ImageView Tooltip style

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8

I have made a global style to be applied to all tooltips, and it is working correctly except when then the tooltip is installed onto an `ImageView`. If I add the tooltip to the ImageView's parent (a `HBox`), the styling is correct, so it can't be a problem with the stylesheet not being added.

The css style looks like this:

```
.tooltip
{
    -fx-border-color: gray;
    -fx-border-radius: 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0;
    -fx-background-radius: 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0;
    -fx-background-color:  white;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-wrap-text: true;
}
```

Adding tooltip to imageview (style doesn't work):

```
 Tooltip.install(imageviewFormat, formatTooltip);
```

Adding tooltip to parent (style does work):

```
 Tooltip.install(imageviewFormat.getParent(), formatTooltip);
```

Am I doing something stupid here, or does ImageView not inherit the css from its parent. Any insight would be appreciated.

**Update**
The following example has this behavior, where `style.css` contains the same tooltip styleclass.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primarystage) throws Exception
    {
        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView("http://www.samjarman.co.nz/images/so.png");
        root.getChildren().add(imageView);

        Tooltip.install(imageView, new Tooltip("Tooltip")); // Doesn't work
        // Tooltip.install(imageView.getParent(), new Tooltip("Tooltip")); // Works

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primarystage.setScene(scene);
        primarystage.show();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Tooltip works for both `ImageView` and `HBox`. I have already tested it. May you can show a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which recreates your problem. **Note :** Use a color for `-fx-text-fill`. *e.g.* `-fx-text-fill: black;`